# How can I unit test Android resources in feature modules?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-resources, androidx, robolectric

My app is using feature modules. One of the feature modules declares a bunch of strings in an xml resource, and then accesses them from my kotlin code: e.g. `getString(R.string.dialog_title)`.  I want to run Junit tests to prove that the correct string content is retrieved.

The [Robolectric documentation page](http://robolectric.org/androidx_test/) suggests using the function `getApplicationContext<MyApplication>()`.  However, you don't have access to the  Application when unit testing a feature module.  I guess that's because feature modules exist separately to the application?

Any help appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Robolectric will slow your unit tests a bit. You can just mock context object and then do something like: `when(context.getString(any()).thenReturn('any/empty string')`

Comment: Thanks. I've used Robolectric before and am aware of its limitations.  I use it sparingly, but as the content of the strings in this scenario is quite important, I'd like automated tests to verify the values are correct.  (In a way, when you use Robolectric it's like using Junit to do more of an integration-style test.).  The method you describe above is more unit style and will only guarantee that my code is interacting with the correct classes.  I want some Android functionality in there to grab the actual values :). It's easy to do in the app module.